# How to set PDF page title from Symfony Controller?

Tags: php, html, symfony

Here is my method in a Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/bilgi/agr", name="user_agreement")
 */
public function agr(): Response
{
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse(__DIR__ . '/../../public/docs/User_Agreement.pdf');
    $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE, $response->getFile()->getFileName());
    return $response;
}
```

I'm expecting to see Page title as **User_Agreement.pdf**, but instead it is `agr`. Which is not appropriate. I can't change the route because it is being used on several other classes/files.

Is there any way I can set a custom title or at least the file name? When I save the file I see the file name as `User_Agreement.pdf` so the file name is also correct.

If that is not possible is there  workaround to show it in twig/html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `<title>`" is an HTML element, not a PDF one.

If a browser renders a PDF directly (as many/most do nowadays), the only thing they could use for a "title" is the URL for the request. `agr` in your case.

It's basically something the server side has no control of. It just sends the response, and the browser decides how to show it, and what to show in the space usually reserved for the `<title>` element.

With the `Content-Disposition` header you can hint the browser about what name they should suggest for the file to the end-user, but that's all.

If you absolutely need this, yes, you could send a regular HTML response and somehow show the PDF inlined/embedded on the page.

Comment: is there  workaround to show it in twig/html?

Comment: If you are sending a PDF (or any kind of binary response), there is no twig/html involved. I guess you could show an HTML page, and then simply show the PDF within an iframe or similar... but that's not "a workaround", that's simply something different.

Comment: I can also send a twig and put it in a twig.

Comment: You can "send a twig and put it in a twig"? Sorry, that doesn't make sense. Maybe you wanted to say something similar to what I suggest in my previous comment. Again, that's not "a workaround", that's simply a different thing. Of course you can send an HTML and put whatever you want within. And yes, in that case you could set the `<title>` tag, but that would be a completely different thing. It wouldn't be "how to set the title to this PDF response?"

Comment: Yes I think you understood what my purpose is, thanks! I want to display in Browser a PDF file and the page should have a custom title.

Comment: Yes, I think I understood correctly. Again, you cannot do this when sending a binary response. That's simply not how a browser works. If you absolutely need this, yes, you could send a regular HTML response and somehow show the PDF inlined in the page. That would be a completely different task. Searching for "show pdf inline embedded" should present you with multiple options.